# Unable to search by JPA "criteria"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an existing JavaFX project in Net-Beans IDE where i have used JDBC. Now i want to use JPA. Generel CRUD operation is working fine. But the problem is in time of search.

I am able to search by JPQL and Native Query. As JPA implementation i am using Hibernate. But the problem is with `CriteriaBuilder`. I am following this link :
[Chapter 9. Criteria Queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).
In this article i have found that i have to use `Metamodel`. As the article refereed i have gone to this article : [Chapter 4. Metamodel](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/metamodel.html#ftn.d0e1922)

According to this article i have created meta model class.

**Main Class**

```
package com.vocubulary.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Model_E2B_WordList
    {
        @Id @Getter @Setter
        private String e2b_word;
    }
```

**Meta Model Class :**

```
package com.vocubulary.model;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;


@StaticMetamodel(Model_E2B_WordList.class)
public  class Model_E2B_WordList_ 
    {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Model_E2B_WordList, String> e2b_word;
    }
```

**DAO Class:**

```
@Test
     public void dao_e2b_get_wordsList_afterSerach_clean()
        {
        String e2b_searchKey = "cat";
        EntityManager entityManager_local = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();
        List<Model_E2B_WordList> list_e2b_wordList = null;
        try
          {
            entityManager_local.getTransaction().begin();
            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager_local.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Model_E2B_WordList> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Model_E2B_WordList.class);
            Root<Model_E2B_WordList> e2b_wordList_Root = criteriaQuery.from(Model_E2B_WordList.class);
            criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(e2b_wordList_Root.get(Model_E2B_WordList_.getE2b_word())), "cat".toLowerCase() + "%"));            
            List<Model_E2B_WordList> e2b_wordList = entityManager_local.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
            System.out.println(" Worlist Length : "+e2b_wordList.size());

            entityManager_local.getTransaction().commit();
          }
        catch (Exception e)
          {
            System.out.println("\n\n\n E2B word by Search Key.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\n\n\n");
            entityManager_local.getTransaction().rollback();
          }
        }
```

My IDE is showing the error is in this line specifically in `Model_E2B_WordList_` here :

```
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(e2b_wordList_Root.get(Model_E2B_WordList_.getE2b_word())), "cat".toLowerCase() + "%"));
```

I have also noticed that there is a package generated:

[image]

Now in my main `package com.vocubulary.model` package i have also a class named as  `Model_E2B_WordList_`. If i am compiling this an compilation  error is showing that :

```
error: duplicate class: com.vocubulary.model.Model_E2B_WordList_
public abstract class Model_E2B_WordList_ {
```

If i am removing the class from my main `package com.vocubulary.model`, then the following error message is being shown:

```
Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 4.3.1.Final
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_102). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: endPosTable already set
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DiagnosticSource.setEndPosTable(DiagnosticSource.java:136)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Log.setEndPosTable(Log.java:350)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:667)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:950)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:892)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:921)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1187)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor539.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:57)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1344)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1070)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute(JavacTask.java:145)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor435.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor435.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor435.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

After search in internet i have found that adding `hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.3.0.final.jar` into class path can be a solution. I have added but the result is same.

Where i have done the mistake?

Comment: Not sure about the compile error, but you are creating the query object from the builder before you added any criteria to the builder. You should try to first add criteria and then create the query.

Comment: sorry i not get your point.

Comment: you say you create JPA Static metamodel "_" classes, but don't say how. They are normally done as part of a precompile step using an annotation processor

Comment: "My IDE is showing the error is in this line specifically in Model_E2B_WordList_ here" What error is your IDE reporting in this line?